# How to change the Vim Syntastic warning color in Airline using Solarized theme

Tags: vim, vim-airline, vim-syntastic

I'm using vim-syntastic and vim-airline using the solarized color theme.

When syntastic has a warning it displays in black on red, which is barely readable:

[image]

After reading the airline help I've tried something like this in my `.vimrc`:

```
call airline#parts#define_accent('syntastic', 'yellow')
```

which seems to have an effect, although 'yellow' is about the only color that is readable and noticeable:

[image]

But I have three questions:

1. I get an error when opening MacVim due to that `call` line:

   ```
   $ mvim index.html 
   Error detected while processing /Users/phil/.vimrc:
   line  304:
   E15: Invalid expression: 0:
   ```

   How do I prevent that?
2. I still get a bit of the error color at the right-edge of airline when there's no syntastic error:

   [image]

   How do I prevent that?
3. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: 1. is a problem in your `.vimrc`, 2. seems to be a bug in `airline`, 3. is a good question for `airline` developers.

Comment: Thanks. I realise there's a problem in my `.vimrc`, caused by that one line, which I copied from the airline help. So I couldn't work out why it was a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to (1) is in two parts:

- I had a colon at the end of the line before the `call` line, which was causing the error.
- I am an idiot.